# Cant select all when tabbing to next control with RTB

Tags: vb.net

I have three rich text boxes. I've set AcceptsTab = True. When I tab the first richtextbox to the second one, all the text is not selected. I've tried using the keydown for the richtextboxes and checking the if it's the tab key and doing selectall. Unfortunately, the event doesnt even get fired. How would i do this? Can anyone help?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow, but it sounds like you just want to call SelectAll in the RTB's Enter event.

Comment: wait, `AcceptTab` is for allowing inserting of the TAB spacing but you seem to be talking about using it to cycle trough the controls. if that is the case you don't want `AcceptTab` to be True

Comment: as for the actual issue @LarsTech suggestion works as advertised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RaphaelSmit pointed out, if you are using the Tab key for navigation, then you want to set  the `AcceptsTab` property to False.

Since you indicated that you are trying to select all of the text when the RichTextBox control gets focused, try using the `Enter` event:

```
Private Sub rtb_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rtb.Enter
  rtb.SelectAll()
End Sub
```